# how to show foreign key value instead of its ID

Tags: django, templates, model, foreign-keys

i'm try to display foreign key value , but it instead return the id , in template

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    pass

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name


class Order(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key = True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product ,through='ProductOrder')
    pass

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.products.all())

 class ProductOrder(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ordering = models.ForeignKey(Order, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    pass


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)
```

this is my views.py

```
class ListOfOrder(ListView):
template_name = 'order/product_group.html'
context_object_name = 'productss'

def get_queryset(self):
    return ProductOrder.objects.all()
```

template.html

```
{% for product in productss %}
    <tr class="">
    <td style="text-align: center;">{{ product.product }}</td>


      {% endfor %}
```

i expected to display the product name but it instead displayed the ID of the product
thanks for your answer